# How to map shapefile polygons to CSV data

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, spatial, shapefile

I downloaded a polygon shape file (england_ct_1991.shp) [from a zip file I downloaded here](https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/England_ct_1991.zip) and CSV file (england_ct_1991.csv) [from a zip file here](https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/csv/England_ct_1991.zip) that I want to connect together (all public data). I added a new column to the CSV file called 'price' so each county has a unique price like this:

```
name,label,x,y,price
Avon,9,360567.1834,171823.554,11
Avon,9,322865.922,160665.4829,11
Bedfordshire,10,506219.5005,242767.306,20
Berkshire,11,464403.02,172809.5331,23....
```

I joined the shp and CSV by the county name. The problem is the map is not superimposing on the price to show a nice color gradient on the counties based on the price. I checked some YouTube tutorials stating the important part is joining but it worked for them so I am unsure what I did wrong?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# map of england counties
map7 <- read_sf("england_ct_1991.shp")
head(map7)

ggplot(map7) +
geom_sf()

# get x (longitude) y (latitude) county names and prices
totalPrices <- read_csv("england_ct_1991.csv")
head(totalPrices)

# join map and csv data on county name
mappedData <- left_join(map7, totalCounts, by="name")
head(mappedData)

# print map
map1 <- ggplot(mappedData, aes( x=x, y=y, group=name)) +
   geom_polygon(aes(fill=price), color="black") +
   geom_sf()

map1
```

Comment: Your csv dataset is saved to `totalPrices` while you are joining `totalCounts`. Pethaps just a typo in the question, but please test posted code to make sure it fails the same way for others. From the example, CSV seems to include values for point locations, what's your desired output for cases where there are multiple rows with the same `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that the warning that `Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between x and y` when running `left_join(map7, totalCounts, by="name")`.

So keep your `totalPrices` data to be unique, that is, no duplicated regions in `name` column.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

map7 <- read_sf("england_ct_1991.shp")

totalPrices <- read_csv("england_ct_1991.csv")

new <- totalPrices %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(price = rnorm(1)) %>% 
  distinct(name, price)
new

## A tibble: 47 × 2
## Groups:   name [47]
#   name                           price
#   <chr>                          <dbl>
# 1 Lincolnshire                 -2.45  
# 2 Cumbria                      -0.413 
# 3 North Yorkshire               0.566 
# 4 Northumberland                0.179 
# 5 Cornwall and Isles of Scilly  1.05  
# 6 Devon                        -0.493 
# 7 Somerset                      0.324 
# 8 Dorset                        0.704 
# 9 East Sussex                   1.32  
#10 Wiltshire                     0.0161
## ℹ 37 more rows
## ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


map7 %>%
  left_join(new) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = price),color="black")
```