# R ggplot geom_text_repel: duplicate colliding label problem

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, r-maptools

This question uses the public data and code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209815/how-to-map-shapefile-polygons-to-csv-data)

I am trying to add labels to my map.  When I use geom_text, each label correctly appears once but collided (right side).  To avoid collision, I am using geom_text_repel (The stick and text make it look cleaner) but when I use it the labels appear multiple times (left side) as you can see in my picture.  Does anyone know what may be the issue?  I tried a inner join instead of a left join but that did not work so I tried manipulating the options in geom_text_repel with no success.  Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629806/remove-duplicate-labels-in-geom-text) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143362/remove-duplicate-labels-in-geom-text) for assistance but still the issue occurs.

[image: England text maps]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)


map7 <- read_sf("england_ct_1991.shp")
totalPrices <- read_csv("england_ct_1991.csv")

new <- totalPrices %>%
 group_by(name) %>%
 mutate(price = rnorm(1)) %>% 
distinct(name, price)
new

map7 %>%
 left_join(new) %>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_sf(aes(fill = price),color="black")

 cnames <- aggregate(cbind(x, y, price) ~ name, data=totalPrices, 
                 FUN=function(x)mean(range(x)))
 head(cnames)
 # cnames code is from [here][4]


map7 %>%
 left_join(cnames) %>%
ggplot() +
 geom_sf(aes(fill = price),color="black")+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    rect = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black", na.value = "red", 
                  guide = 'colorbar', aesthetics = 'fill') +
  #geom_text( aes(x, y, label = name)) +
  geom_text_repel( aes(x, y, label = name, geometry = geometry), stat = "sf_coordinates",
      show.legend=FALSE, size = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are multiple sets of geometry within the same name. One fix of this is to keep one name only for those multiple sets of geometry. A quick solution is to keep the first name and replace the rest with NA or " ".

```
map7 %>%
  left_join(cnames) %>%
  mutate(name_1 = ifelse(row_number() == 1, name, NA), .by = name) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = price), color = "black") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    rect = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    low = "white", high = "black", na.value = "red",
    guide = "colorbar", aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x, y, label = name_1, geometry = geometry),
    stat = "sf_coordinates",
    show.legend = FALSE, size = 3
  )
```

[image]

Alternatively, we could manually choose which name to use.

Comment: That was a great idea, thanks a lot!